# Alternative to wrapping all callback functions in anonymous functions in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

I started using CoffeeScript today and found myself using a pattern like `(args...) => @style(args...)` a lot when I needed callback function. The context looks roughly like this:

```
class Parent
  @style: (feature) ->
    if feature
      @insight()

class Child extends Parent
  @insight: ->
    alert 'Sara is awesome'

  @load: ->
    [42].forEach((args...) => @style(args...))

Child.load()
```

This shows `Sara is awesome`, which is accurate. If I had only used `[42].forEach(@style)`, `style` would’ve ended up with a `this` referring to the parent class (I think?), which doesn’t know `insight`.

But this is very verbose, and I need a lot of callback functions in my code. Is there a more elegant, idiomatic way to solve this?

(Using `forEach` in CoffeeScript is bad style I’ve read, but in my actual code I’m working with various Leaflet functions that I can’t just replace with for loops.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to noticed is that you shouldn't call `insight` from the `Parent` class. The whole purpose of a class is to provide encapsulation. So the first thing I'd do is to move `insight` to `Parent`

To answer your question, the more idiomatic way to solve that is using the fat arrow notation. What the fat arrow does internally is to create an anonymous function to enclosure the `this`.

That said, the final code should look something like this:

```
class Parent
  @style: (feature) =>
    if feature
      @insight()

  @insight: ->
    alert 'Sara is awesome'

class Child extends Parent
  @load: ->
    [42].forEach(@style)

Child.load()
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

Based on the OP comment:

```
class Parent
  style: (feature) =>
    if feature
      @insight()

class Child extends Parent
  load: ->
    [42].forEach(@style)

  insight: ->
    alert 'Sara is awesome'

(new Child()).load()
```

Comment: Thanks! But `insight` needs to be a `Child` method. Every child has a different one, and there is no sane default (the classes represent types of markers on a map, each subclass distinguished by hues of a different color). There are other `Parent` methods that do have sane defaults, so the abstract `Parent` serves a purpose as opposed to a duck-typing solution. (So long as `insight` in not in `Parent`, the `=>` doesn’t produce the right result.)

Should I add several child classes to my example to make it clearer?

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. In that case the problem is that when you define your methods with @ you are creating a class method, class methods don't know about the child because inheritance take effect on instances. Let me edit the answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: The new version works like a charm, thank you! I didn’t know about that peculiarity of inheritance. Good to know!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!